# Difference in days between two dates as integer

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

This code

```
(this.ApprovedDate - this.ReceivedDate).TotalDays
```

gives me a `double` typed value.

How do I get the integer one rounded up? Assuming that this.ApprovedDate and this.ReceivedDate are both DateTime type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Math library and cast to int.

Example:

```
    var a = new TimeSpan(5, 14, 0, 0);  // 5 days, 14 hours
    var x = a.Days;  // Does not round up. = 5 
    var y = (int) Math.Round(a.TotalDays);  // Rounds up. = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`TotalDays` gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional days. Instead you should be using the integer `Days` property which gets the days component of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure, see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx).

Please note that using `Days` gives the whole number of days between two dates and will ignore fractions. Depending on your requirements you may want to round `TotalDays` to zero digits instead and cast it to an integer as proposed by MutantNinjaCodeMonkey.

Comment: Depending on the timestamps, that can be correct. There is only one whole day between 18 Dec 09:00 an 20 Dec 08:00. You will have to round 'TotalDays` as proposed by @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey.